# Android service vs thread

Tags: android, multithreading, service

1. is a service more difficult to debug ?
2. can I guarantee that
   the service is always running after installing the app ?ist item
3. can a service send the user push notifications ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should really try not to pollute stackoverflow with so badly written questions.
2. Please read the doc. A Service is not a way to implement multithreading. By default a service run on the main (UI) thread.
3. Your first question does not make sense because it can be more difficult or less difficult on the basis of what they do
4. For your second question: [Trying to start a service on boot on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android)
5. For your third question: a Service can do whatever an app can do